# System.IO.FileNotFoundException has mysterious forward slash

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm at a loss. I've been trying to debug this:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/C:\Users\Jehy\source\repos\Portfolio\demoJSON\demoquery.json"
```

I am able to access the file at that path by pasting the exact same thing into CMD.

I've tried separating all the directories into a list and letting Path.Combine do all the work. I've tried adding and removing the file extension.

```
string filepath = Path.Combine(new string[] { @"C:\Users\Jehy\source\repos\Portfolio\demoJSON\demoquery.json"});

Debug.WriteLine(filepath);
List<DataObject> data = ParseJSON(LoadJSON(filepath));
```

What's most confusing to me is the / being added before C:\ in the error message.

Edit:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/C:\'.
```

From

```
string filepath = @"C:\";

Debug.WriteLine(Directory.GetFiles(filepath));
```

This makes me think that my code is trying to access the files on the emulated device. Am I able to access files from my computer instead?

---

**Final Edit:**

It turns out that I've been navigating through my emulated device, which should have been obvious. I'll find a different way to solve my problem. If anyone stumbles across this question, the '/' being added at the beginning of the filepath was due to this.

Comment: Why are you calling Path.Combine when you are not combining any paths? That is likely where the problem is coming from, just get rid it and do `string filepath = @"C:\Users\Jehy\source\repos\Portfolio\demoJSON\demoquery.json"`

Comment: Also, the fact that you are using Xamarin makes me beleve you are not building a normal .NET desktop app. Possibly a windows store app? Those have restrictions on what files you can load and how to load them, if it is not in the directory of the app you normally have to have a user interaction like a open file dialog to get access to anything

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'll look into that file loading. I didn't know that could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
string filepath = @"C:\Users\Jehy\source\repos\Portfolio\demoJSON\demoquery.json";
```

Should work, but I suggest avoiding absolute file paths, as it will not work if you try to execute it on a different machine.

I would suggest using a relitive path by putting the demoJSON folder in the same directory as your executable and using

```
string filepath = Path.Combine("demoJSON", "demoquery.json");
```

Comment: I'll try that. I'm not worried about absolute file paths, just loading some sample data.